# Pointer Lock issue in CefSharp (WPF)

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I have recently started working on a WPF browser application using the CefSharp framework and have hit a bit of an issue with the Pointer Lock API.

When trying to lock the pointer I am receiving the following error within the Visual Studio console.

`Uncaught (in promise) WrongDocumentError: The root document of this element is not valid for pointer lock.`

However, I have come across some further information on Bitbucket for the CefSharp framework stating that Pointer Lock hasn't been implemented yet this was back in 2020 and I am beginning to wonder if my Javascript implementation is wrong or if the Pointer Lock API still isn't supported yet.

I understand that most browsers support this functionality and that most browsers are running on the Chromium framework and that CefSharp is a port of that minus the UI and other bits and pieces.

Is there any way to implement this into my own project source code or even compile CefSharp from the source with the Pointer Lock functionality or would I need to use another framework that currently supports this?

**Javascript**

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("my-canvas");

canvas.onclick = () => {
    canvas.requestPointerLock();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CefSharp is just one of many Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) wrappers. Still waiting on upstream support for pointer locking to be added in CEF. Supported has to be added in CEF first before it can be added to CefSharp.

There is an open PR https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/338 though it's been inactive for a long time.

Comment: Possibility you can inject a https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Polyfill to achieve the desired behaviour. Use your favorite search engine pointer lock polyfill to see if there are any you can use as a reference. CefSharp.PostMessage can be used to communicate with the .Net application, https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2775#issuecomment-498454221 see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Thank you for your response @amaitland and for providing a workaround for the above. I have implemented pointer lock into the CEF source. So far I have built this and tested it using cefclient.exe so far all seems to be working well. 

As pointer lock has been implemented into the CEF source does this also need implementation into the CefSharp framework or is it just a case of copying the libcef.dll and other dependencies?

I have set the GN_DEFINES as follows.

is_component_build=false
is_official_build=true

Comment: So I have now compiled from the source and added the libcef.dll to the C# project root now I am receiving the following exception.

`Exception Info: System.InvalidOperationException
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.NoInliningConstructor()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor()
   at UNS.MainWindow.InitializeChromium()
   at UNS.MainWindow..ctor()`

Comment: To package a CEF build for use with CefSharp the PowerShell script within the https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary repo is used. Look at the source to see the supported args. Once you have generated the Nuget packages you can then build your own version of CefSharp from source.

Comment: Great thank you I appreciate the help with this one. I wasn't building the CefSharp or nuget packages with the new binaries.